# Qt on Android: How to import extra packages in a custom Activity?

Tags: java, android, qt

I'm trying to add licensing to my app and need to import the following files in my main activity (I have extended `org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity` and that part works):

```
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseCheckerCallback;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.ServerManagedPolicy;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.AESObfuscator;
```

I have that needed LVL stuff installed in the SDK that is also configured in Qt Creator, but I'm still getting errors when compiling:

```
error: error: package com.google.android.vending.licensing does not exist
```

Where/what/how should I configure to make this work?

Comment: As a quick workaround I just copied the needed files from the Android SDK to my source dir, but that's not a real solution :)

Comment: Shouldn't it work directly from the SDK location? After all it is set in Creator's Android settings. Copying like that seems like a hassle.

Comment: I don't know. The LVL stuff is not part of the "default" Android SDK and lies under Sdk/extras after installation.